# FFmpeg Batch loop through files in two different folders at the same time

Tags: windows, loops, for-loop, batch-file, ffmpeg

I have files in two folders like this

```
Video
 record01.mkv
 record02.mkv
Audio
 audio1.avi
 audio2.avi
Merged
```

I would like to run a loop to combine the files in the folders with one-to-one correspondence based on alphabetical order (es. first file in "Video" folder combines with first file in "Audio" folder and so on)

The command I need to use is simple:

```
ffmpeg -i "record01.mkv" -i "audio1.avi" -map 0 -map 1 -map -1:v -c copy ".\Merged\record01.mkv"
```

I tried with the following command but it didn't work (as I expected since files in the two different folders have different names)

```
FOR /R %%i IN (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i ".\Video\%%i" -i ".\Audio\%%i" -map 0 -map 1 -map -1:v -c copy ".\Merged\%%~dni.mkv"
```

Thank you!

Comment: well on linux I would suggest pipe i am not sure about windows
```ls Video | ffmpeg -i ```

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to read two files in parallel (or one file and one command output): use a `for` loop for one input-stream and redirection plus `set /p` for the other (this one has to be a file):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   
dir /b /s /on audio\*.avi > audioFiles
< audioFiles (for /f %%a in ('dir /on /b /s video\*.mkv') do (
  set /p "audio="
  echo %%a, !audio!
))
```

I trust you are able to implement the `ffmpeg` command yourself.